# C program connect: connect: Invalid argument

Tags: c, sockets, ipv6

Im trying to write a program to connect with IPv6 client and server. it is very simple but it says that `connect: invalid argument`. I learned IPv6 for a while. the code following is modified from IPv4 client. did I miss something? I need some help!!

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int ClientSocket;
    struct sockaddr_in6 ServerAddress;

    if((ClientSocket = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
        perror("socket");

    bzero(&ServerAddress, sizeof(ServerAddress));
    ServerAddress.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    ServerAddress.sin6_port = htons(4002);

    if(inet_pton(AF_INET6, "fe80::0214:97ff:fe13:257b", &ServerAddress.sin6_addr) <= 0)
        perror("inet_pton");

    if(connect(ClientSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&ServerAddress, sizeof(ServerAddress)) < 0)
        perror("connect");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you use a link-local address, you must also use a Scope/Zone ID.

Comment: @RonMaupin you mean, in my case, fe80::0214:97ff:fe13:257b%64 ?

Comment: That is a link-local address. Any address in the `fe80::/10` range is an IPv6 link-local address.

Comment: @RonMaupin it works!! thanks for your tip!!